# How to write the correct AJAX URL in Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel-5

My AJAX file

```js
function getLead(id) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "{{ url('leads/get_lead') }}",
    data: id,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
}
```

The result in console

> GET
>   http://127.0.0.1:8000/reservation/%7B%7B%20url('//leads/get_lead/')%20%7D%7D?_=1537345882551
>   404 (Not Found)

As you see it prints the whole URL as if it is a string.

Do I write the URL in a wrong way?

Comment: it looks to me like your template string is not being parsed. Is this code located in your view file or in a separate .js file?

Comment: separate JS file, and when i used url like this:  var url = "leads/get_lead/" + id;

Comment: that'll be why then - the PHP interpreter only works on view files. JS files are not included in this. I suggest you follow something like the answer below, or change your function so that you pass in the URL as a parameter when you call it from the view (that way you can run the PHP code in the view to generate the URL, and then pass it to the JS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be a good way - even if it has a problem - but what if you want to access the main url from an external JS file?
For me. I define the main url in my header file

```
<script>
    APP_URL = '{{url('/')}}' ;
</script>
```

And access this variable from anywhere.

So for your case your ajax request will be:

```
function getLead(id) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: APP_URL + '/leads/get_lead',
    data: id,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
}
```